# django context form not rendered after form invalid

Tags: python, django, forms, templates, view

I have a doctor detail view in which I have passed form as context:

```
class HospitalDoctorDetailView(DetailView):
context = {}
model = HospitalDoctor
template_name = "hospital_doctor_detail.html"
context_object_name = 'doctor'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(HospitalDoctorDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['appointment_form'] = AppointmentForm1
    return context
```

And I have used this form in the template named `hospital_doctor_detail.html`:

```
<form action="/appointment/{{doctor.id}}/{{doctor.hospital.id}}/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
First Name:<br/>
{{ form.first_name.errors }}
{{ appointment_form.first_name }}<br/>
Middle Nmae:<br/>
{{ form.middle_name.errors }}
{{ appointment_form.middle_name }}<br/>
Last Name:<br/>
{{ form.last_name.errors }}
{{appointment_form.last_name}}<br/>
Age:<br/>
{{ form.age.errors }}
{{ appointment_form.age }}<br/>
Date:<br/>
{{ form.appointment_date.errors }}
{{ appointment_form.appointment_date }}<br/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Take Appointment" style="background-color:#EFEFEF; border:1px solid #000;" />
</form>
```

My form AppointmentForm1 is a model form. To submit a form I have written a view:

```
def TakeAppointmentView(request, pk, hpk):
doctor = HospitalDoctor.objects.get(pk=pk)
hospital = Hospital.objects.get(pk=hpk)
if request.method == "POST":
    form = AppointmentForm1(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        app = DoctorAppointment()
        app.user = request.user
        app.doctor = doctor
        app.hospital = hospital
        app.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
        app.middle_name = form.cleaned_data['middle_name']
        app.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
        app.age = form.cleaned_data['age']
        app.appointment_date = form.cleaned_data['appointment_date']
        app.save()
        messages.success(request, "Thank you for taking appointment")
        return redirect("doctor_detail", pk)
        #return redirect("/home/")
    else:
        return render_to_response("hospital_doctor_detail.html", {"appointment_form":form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
else:
    form = AppointmentForm1()
return render_to_response("hospital_doctor_detail.html", {"appointment_form":form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

If the form is valid appointment is taken successfully but if the form is invalid I want to redirect it to the same doctor detail view.

Here I am getting an error that if the form is invalid it is redirecting to the doctor detail view with the error message  but form is not displayed??
Whats wrong in here??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning your form to your template as `{"application_form": form}`.

You're template doesn't know anything about any variables called `form`.

Instead of using:

```
{{ form.first_name.errors }}
```

Try using the following for each of your error messages:

```
{{ application_form.first_name.errors }}
```